# User defined table types in Oracle

Tags: oracle

First of all usually I am working with MSSQL. But I have a stored procedure in MSSQL, which I need to use in Oracle now and since I am absolutely new to Oracle I have no idea at all how to do it correct.

I needed to use user defined table types in my MS SQL stored procedure because I am using "logical" tables in my stored procedure, which I also need to pass them to a dynamic sql statement within this procedure (using column names of "physical" tables as variables/parameters).

I've started to add the oracle function in a package I made before for another function. It looks like

```
TYPE resultRec IS RECORD
(
   [result columns] 
);

TYPE resultTable IS TABLE OF resultRec;

Function MyFunctionName([A LOT PARAMETERS]) RETURN resultTable PIPELINED;
```

I also described the layout of the tables (the user defined table types in MSSQL), which I want to use within this function in this package header. 
So far so good, but now I don't really know where I have to declare my table variables or user defined table types. I also tried to put them in the package header, but if I am trying to use these tables in the package body, where I am describing my function, Oracle tells met, that the table or view does not exist.
I also tried it to describe the tables within the package body or in the block of my function, which looks like that:

```
FUNCTION MyFunctionName
(
   [MyParameters]
)
RETURN resultTable PIPELINED is rec resultrec;

TYPE tableVariableA IS TABLE OF tableRecA;
TYPE tableVariableB IS TABLE OF tableRecB;

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO tableVariableA
  SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM physicalTable WHERE[...];

  [A LOT MORE TO DO...]
END;
```

But in this case Oracle also tells me, that it doesn't know the table or view.
I also tried a few more things, but at the end I wasn't able to tell Oracle what table it should use...
I would appreciate every hint, which helps me to understand how oracle works in this case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert into a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm) (e.g. PL/SQL table). You can [use the bulk collect syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS891) to populate the collection:

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
BULK COLLECT INTO tableVariableA
FROM physicalTable
WHERE [...];
```

However, you might want to check this is an appropriate approach, since SQL Server and Oracle differ quite a bit. You can't use PL/SQL tables in plain SQL ([at least prior to 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS111)), even inside your procedure, so you *might* need a schema-level type rather than a PL/SQL type, but it depends what you will do next. You might not really want a collection at all. Trying to convert T-SQL straight to PL/SQL without understanding the differences could lead you down a wrong path - make sure you understand the actual requirement and then find the best Oracle mechanism for that.

Comment: Alex, just a nitpick... Starting with 11g (I guess) you can use packaged collection types in pipelined table functions. Oracle creates the respective schema level types (with the SYS_PLSQL prefix usually) for you in the background as a result of the package compilation.

Comment: @nop77svk - [I think that's from 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS111), but good point, I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Alex, that's about ability to pass pure PL/SQL types to NDSQL (via execute immediate). The one I mean is [here, in the "Return data type" section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS834).

Comment: @nop77svk - ah, OK, thanks. (In the OP's situation the elements of the collection type are not SQL types, they're PL/SQL records, so still not allowed in this specific case; but still useful in general).

Comment: Nope. Still allowed. As long as the records contain only elements of SQL types (or even schema-level object types, too), a collection of such records still could be used in a pipelined TF, "mirrors" of such packaged types still would be autocreated under the hoods on the schema level.

The Oracle doc is not specific on this one, it's an experience more of my own.